# Struct @State class did not set by button correctly

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, foreach

I want to open a Detail View in SwiftUI by pressing a Button.
For each object (CourseClub Class) I've got a button to set the `self.CourseClub` to the right for-each-object.

EDIT:
It don't work for the first clicked button. The first clicked object, generated by the forEach does not set the self.clubCourse to the selected object. When I click another button the second time, it works perfectly and when I re-click the first button, it's working too. But not for the first click. Doesn't matter which button, the first click does not work.

This is my DetailView:

```swift
var section: KursSection
@EnvironmentObject var vm: TimetableViewModel
var stundenkurse = [CourseStunden]()
@State var showClubPanel = false 
@State var watchingClub = CourseClub(name: "", image: "", sorting: "", dates: [CourseDate(id: "", day: 1, time: Date.now, room: "", startDate: Date.now)])
  
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ScrollView {
                cover
                sections
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .background()
            .sheet(isPresented: $showClubPanel) {
                CourseDetailView(course: watchingClub)
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            }
        }
    }

    var sections: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12){
            ForEach(section.sectionsClub){ stufe in
                Text(stufe.section.uppercased())
                    .font(.footnote.weight(.semibold))
                    .padding(.vertical)
                if(stufe.array.count == 0){
                    Text("Momentan keine Termine für diesen Kurs")
                        .font(.footnote)
                } else {
                    ForEach(stufe.array){ kurs in
                        Button{
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                                self.watchingClub = kurs
                                showClubPanel = true
                            }
                        } label: {
                            HStack{
                                Text(kurs.name)
                                    .padding()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .offset(y: 100)
        .padding(.bottom, 200)
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
```

this is my CourseClub Class, which I am looping:

```
struct CourseClub: Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
let name: String
let image: String
let sorting: String
var dates = [CourseDate]()
var sortingInt = 0 }
```

And this is my main View, from which I am navigating to the detail view. In there I pass a KursSection with title, image and the important part, the KursSectionClub array. Each KursSectionClub item got a name and and CourseClub array, which I am looping in the detail view with the issue. Telled above.

```
ScrollView{
            ForEach(sectionData){ section in
                Button{
                    self.section = section
                    shouldNavigate.toggle()
                } label: {
                    KursSectionItem(title: section.title, subtitle: section.subtitle, img: section.img)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Kursübersicht")
        }
        .onAppear(){
            sectionData = [
                KursSection(title: "Erwachsene", subtitle: "Alle Tanzkurse für Erwachsene", img: "//...", sectionsClub: [KursSectionClub(section: "Tanzcards", array: vm.coursesClubErwachsene)]),
            ] // ...}
```

I want to `ForEach` loop all courses and display a button, with `self.watchingKurs = [looped Course]` when clicking.
The first click does not update and the Detail View shows my first (with empty Strings) declared watchingKurs `@State` var.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Don't `toggle()` `showClubPanel`, set it to `true` when you want the view displayed.  Being specific in your actions helps avoid unpredictable behaviour. You also need to update the Q with all the relevant components to give a full MRE.

Answer (score 0):

With this limited information I may not be 100% sure what is wrong with your code, but I'd like to try.

First of all, in order to debug your code you should checkmark some boxes. *Firstly* verify your **button is actually being triggered**. You can add breakpoints or print statements for that purpose. *Secondly*, be sure to initialize `showClubPanel` properly. It needs to be declared **before** your SwiftUI view body.

I'm assuming you have done everything, let's get to what I have in mind. Sometimes, SwiftUI state updates need to happen on the **main thread**. This part of SwiftUI always confuses, I'm not sure why. I may need to read more docs.

So, wrapping the button action code in `DispatchQueue.main.async` could help ensure the **UI updates as expected**.

```swift
Button {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // here is the magical part (i hope)
        self.watchingClub = kurs
        showClubPanel.toggle()
    }
} label: {
    // rest of your code
}
```

Hope this solves your issue. Feel free to provide more information about your code so that we could find a solution, if this one doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you leopanic, but your try does not solve the issue. I will edit my question to give more information and code. thx

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Hope we can solve this issue soon. Additional information will definitely help

Comment: I have edited my question with more information. You need something else? :)